# GitLab Coexisting with SSHD on Bridge Interface

Tags: docker, sshd, bridge, gitlab, podman

**Background**

I am attempting to convert a server from using Docker to Podman.  So far I have been able to convert all of my services (~15 in total) to systemd jobs and run them without issue.  In doing so, I have created a bridge device (`br0`) and added both the physical interface (`eno1`) and the pod's `veth` interface to it.  A further container running `bind` is attached to the bridge using the `macvlan` driver.  Thus far, everything is functioning exactly as I would expect.

**Problem**

Now, I am attempting to bring up GitLab in a container and want to make use of standard ports 22 and 443.  As these ports are below 1024, I have to invoke this container as root and then later switch to other users (the official `gitlab-ce` container uses 8 different users total).  Whenever I try to start the container I receive the following error:

```
podman[1161766]: Error: cannot listen on the TCP port: listen tcp4 :22: bind: address already in use
```

This is baffling to me as I have already configured sshd to only listen on the specific `br0` IP address (physical hosts have /24 addresses >= 100, containers have /24 addresses between 4 and 99):

```
ListenAddress 192.168.1.104
```

This is then verified with netstat:

```
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.104:22        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      695475/sshd
```

The container is configured to start with a different MAC (`FE:ED:DE:AD:BE:EF`) and IP (`192.168.1.15`) from the host system.

**Question**

What else would be using port 22?

Failing this, how would I go about finding the culprit given that netstat only shows sshd using port 22?

As far as I am aware, this should work.  Even though the container switches to non-root users internally the OCI runtime is invoked from a root context so, when it tries to configure the networking interface, it should be able to bind to the port.  This is further verified by the DNS container which is able to bind to port 53 without issue.